# Elasticsearch Nest incorrect function_Score JSON generation

Tags: function, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-query

I am trying to build the following function for the function_score search query:

```
{
    "filter": {
        "range": {
            "availabilityAverage": {
                "gt": 0
            }
        }
    },
    "field_value_factor": {
        "field": "availabilityAverage",
        "factor": 1,
        "modifier": "log1p"
    },
    "weight": 100
}
```

This is currently my .Net code

```
.FieldValueFactor(ff => ff
    .Field(fff => fff.StandardPriceMin)                             
    .Factor(2)
    .Modifier(FieldValueFactorModifier.Log1P)
    .Weight(100)
    .Filter(faf => faf
        .Range(r => r
            .Field(rf => rf.AvailabilityAverage)
            .GreaterThan(0.0)
        )
    )
)
```

However, this is the result of the NEST query:

```
{
    "filter": {
        "range": {
            "availabilityAverage": {
                "gt": 0.0
            }
        }
    },
    "field_value_factor": {
        "factor": 2.0,
        "field": "standardPriceMin",
        "modifier": "log1p",
        "filter": {
            "range": {
                "availabilityAverage": {
                    "gt": 0.0
                }
            }
        },
        "weight": 100.0
    },
    "weight": 100.0
}
```

It is adding correctly the filter and weight on the outside of **field_value_factor** but also including the 'Filter' and 'weight' on the **inside** as a child element. This is not the case for others such as RandomScore() with exact same format but only with field_value_factor.

I tried several different combinations but neither provided expected result. Is it normal that the NEST is generating this JSON?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a bug in how `IFieldValueFactorFunction` is being serialized, resulting in `filter` and `weight` being included twice, outside of `"field_value_factor"` and inside. [I've opened a pull request to address](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/pull/4978).